# how to do url join in python using multiple parameters

Tags: python

I am having a simple doubt..
   I am trying to join three parts of a string using urljoin..

```
   host = "http://foo.com:port"
   ver = "/v1"
   exten = "/path"
```

Rather than doing host+ver+exten, I want to use urljoin to generate url
   But urljoin is giving 
   `http://foo.com:poort/v1` ( if i try `urljoin(host,ver,exten)` )

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) seem like that's not how urljoin works. Maybe try [urlunsplit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunsplit)

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me: Not sure, i understand.. can you give an example.. urlunsplit will split the url?? Right?

Comment: Sorry. Urlunsplit doesn't do quite what I thought it does. It will only join tuple of type `urlparse.SplitResult'. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

The way `urljoin` works is by combining a base URL and another URL. You could try joining the relative paths together with simple string combinations, and then use `urljoin` to join the host and the combined relative path.

Like:

```
rel = ver + exten
url = urljoin(host, rel)
```

Sadly if you want to combine multiple URL paths, you will have to use another library. If you're using a non-Windows machine, you could use the os.path module to join them together just like you would combine a local file path.

Comment: Can you suggest any libraries to join multiple URL paths in python?

Comment: **from urllib.parse import urljoin**

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it on linux(python 2.x):

```
import urlparse
import os
def url_join(host, version, *additional_path):
    return urlparse.urljoin(host, os.path.join(version, *additional_path))
```

and then call this function like:

```
>> url_join("http://example.com:port", "v1", "path1", "path2", "path3")
>> 'http://example.com:port/v1/path1/path2/path3
```

Comment: os.path.join doesn't use the right separator in Win machines. -->  ' ```'http://foo.com:port/v1\\path1\\path2\\path3'```

Comment: Us should use `import posixpath`.
When you import `os.path` on any nix* you will get `posixpath` and on any windows you will get `ntpath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also join your list of parts recursively:

```
def urljoin(parts):
    if len(parts) > 1:
        parts = [urllib.parse.urljoin(parts[0], parts[1])] + parts[2:]
        return urljoin(parts)

    return parts[0]
```

Use the function like this:

```
parts = [
    'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    'questions/24814657/',
    'how-to-do-url-join-in-python-using-multiple-parameters/',
    '41756140#41756140',
]

print(urljoin(parts))
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814657/how-to-do-url-join-in-python-using-multiple-parameters/41756140#41756140
```

Note that `urllib.parse.urljoin()` has a bit different behavior than `os.path.join()` mentioned by @AnukuL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [str.**join**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function, as suggested in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189633):

```
url = urljoin('http://example.com:port', '/'.join(['v1','path']))
```

If the path segments contains one or more slash `/`, use [str.**strip**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) first:

```
path='/'.join(map(lambda s: s.strip('/'), ["/v1", "/path"]))
url = urljoin('http://example.com:port', path)
```