# Python: Join multiple components to build a URL

Tags: python, url-parsing

I am trying to build a URL by joining some dynamic components. I thought of using something like `os.path.join()` BUT for URLs in my case. From research I found `urlparse.urljoin()` does the same thing. However, it looks like it only take two arguments at one time.

I have the following so far which works but looks repetitive:

```
    a = urlparse.urljoin(environment, schedule_uri)
    b = urlparse.urljoin(a, str(events_to_hours))
    c = urlparse.urljoin(b, str(events_from_date))
    d = urlparse.urljoin(c, str(api_version))
    e = urlparse.urljoin(d, str(id))
    url = e + '.json'
```

Output = `http://example.com/schedule/12/20160322/v1/1.json`

The above works and I tried to make it shorter this way:

```
url_join_items = [environment, schedule_uri, str(events_to_hours),
                  str(events_from_date), str(api_version), str(id), ".json"]
new_url = ""
for url_items in url_join_items:
    new_url = urlparse.urljoin(new_url, url_items)
```

Output: `http://example.com/schedule/.json`

But the second implementation does not work. Please suggest me how to fix this or the better way of doing it.

EDIT 1:
The output from the `reduce` solution looks like this (unfortunately):
Output: `http://example.com/schedule/.json`

Comment: @idjaw: In my case I am already sure I want to use `urlparse`, I just need a cleaner and shorter way of joining more than 2 components to the same url

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It looks mostly good to me. What's the output and what's wrong with it? You probably want to stick to string concatenation for the `.json` so that your URL doesn't end in `/.json` though. Also I don't know how it's going to handle an empty string so you may want to start with `new_url = url_join_items[0]` and then iterate over `url_join_items[1:]`. But the answer with reduce is probably better.

Comment: @AlexHall: Please see my EDIT 1 and Output from each method

Comment: OK, again, leave the `.json` out of `url_join_items`. Otherwise, I can't understand why so many parts are missing. What happens if you `print url_join_items`?

Comment: @AlexHall: I get this: `['http://example.com', 'schedule/', '12', '20160322', 'v1', '100', '.json']`

Comment: `urljoin('http://example.com/schedule/12', '20160322')` returns `'http://example.com/schedule/20160322'` which is probably not what you want. I'm not sure why it does that but that's your problem. Perhaps avoid it and simply use `'/'.join(url_join_items)`. You'll want to make sure there's no extra slashes in the items though. A quick way is `item.strip('/')` but if there's more than one slash at the end it'll strip them all which you probably don't want.

Comment: In my response, I provide a link to a related question that explains what urljoin is doing, and why you are seeing the results with "missing" parts. I also suggest "/".join, which is straightforward and concise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Using join**

Have you tried simply `"/".join(url_join_items)`. Does not http always use the forward slash? You might have to manually setup the prefix "https://" and the suffix, though.

Something like:

```
url = "https://{}.json".format("/".join(url_join_items))
```

**Using reduce and urljoin**

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893374/python-confusions-with-urljoin) on SO that explains to some degree the thinking behind the implementation of `urljoin`. Your use case does not appear to be the best fit.

When using `reduce` and `urljoin`, I'm not sure it will do what the question intends, which is semantically like `os.path.join`, but for urls. Consider the following:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from functools import reduce

parts_1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
parts_2 = ["https://","server.com","somedir","somefile.json"]
parts_3 = ["https://","server.com/","somedir/","somefile.json"]

out1 = reduce(urljoin, parts_1)
print(out1)
```

> `d`

```
out2 = reduce(urljoin, parts_2)
print(out2)
```

> `https:///somefile.json`

```
out3 = reduce(urljoin, parts_3)
print(out3)
```

> `https:///server.com/somedir/somefile.json`

Note that with the exception of the extra "/" after the https prefix, the third output is probably closest to what the asker intends, except we've had to do all the work of formatting the parts with the separator.

Comment: Do you think it's a cleaner approach than what I already have working?

Comment: Yes. I think it is, but that's subjective.

Answer (score 6):

I also needed something similar and came up with this solution:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin, quote_plus

def multi_urljoin(*parts):
    return urljoin(parts[0], "/".join(quote_plus(part.strip("/"), safe="/") for part in parts[1:]))

print(multi_urljoin("https://server.com", "path/to/some/dir/", "2019", "4", "17", "some_random_string", "image.jpg"))
```

This prints `'https://server.com/path/to/some/dir/2019/4/17/some_random_string/image.jpg'`

Comment: Underated answer! I made something similar, but without the `quote_plus`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution will be:

```
def url_join(*parts: str) -> str:
    import re

    line = '/'.join(parts)
    line = re.sub('/{2,}', '/', line)
    return re.sub(':/', '://', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit silly but workable solution, given that `parts` is a list of URL parts in order

```
my_url = '/'.join(parts).replace('//', '/').replace(':/', '://')
```

I wish `replace` would have a `from` option but it does not hence the second one is to recover `https://` double slash

Nice thing is you don't have to worry about parts already having (or not having) any slashes

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me all the best:

```py
def join_url_parts(base: str, parts: list[str], allow_fragments: bool = True) -> str:
    """Join multiple URL parts together.

    See the examples below. All of them would produce the same result:
    `https://example.com/api/v1/users/`

        print(join_url_parts("https://example.com", ["api", "v1", "users"]))
        print(join_url_parts("https://example.com", ["api", "v1/", "users"]))
        print(join_url_parts("https://example.com/", ["api/", "v1/", "users/"]))
        print(join_url_parts("https://example.com/", ["/api/", "/v1/", "users/"]))
    """
    url = "/".join(map(lambda x: str(x).strip("/"), parts)) + "/"
    return urljoin(base, url, allow_fragments)
```

This basically replicates the standard `urljoin` but allows the second arguments to be parts (list of strings).